# Why does my header center its children vertically?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble understanding the default behavior of `display: flex`

Why does my `header` vertically centers its children when I only add `display: flex` to it.

I have not added `align-items: center;` to the `header`.

Is it because I assigned it `height: 100px;`?

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
}

header div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1224px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

nav a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 55px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <nav>
      <a href="#">one</a>
      <a href="#">two</a>
      <a href="#">three</a>
     </nav>
     <a href="#">Link</a>
  </div>
</header>
```

I am aware that the `div` has `display: flex` and `align-items: center;` But why does the parent html element `header` also need `display: flex` for its children to vertically center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply `display: flex` to the parent `div`, its children "stretch" to assume the full height and width of the container, since the default [`align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) property is `stretch`.

Hence, the child of the `header` now has a height of `100px` (previously the height of its content), and the content is centered.

Your solution (to apply `height: 100%`) works since the content's height is now `100px` (the height of the container), essentially simulating flexbox's vertical stretch.

Comment: Removing `display: flex` from the `header` and giving my `div` a `height` of `100%` gave me the solution I wanted

Answer (score 0):

It is not aligning vertically the `header`, it is aligning vertically the `div` inside the `header`.

Your `header > div` has `display:flex` and `align-items: center` which is explicit telling the `div` to align items to the center.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `display: flex;` on parents with only one child.
Your `<header>` tag has `100px` of height and **by default your `<div>` has implicit `align-self: stretch;`** which is like you do `height: 100%` on it. For solving your problem you have two options:

- Remove `display: flex;` from your `<header> tag`.
- Asign `align-self: flex-start;` to your `<div>`.

Apply these two options to the `<div>` children for achieve the same results if you consider. The main key of this answer is: **All children of a flex container has an implicit `align-self: stretch` by default.**

Comment: I did what you suggested, but the children are not centered, unless I misinterpreted your instructions.

https://codesandbox.io/s/header-center-chlyl?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: In the case you need the children vertically centered, also add `height: 100%` to `<div>` keping `display: flex` removed from `<header>` tag. For this solution please, dont asign `align-self: flex-start;` to the `<div>`. It is not necessary anymore.